# Couldn't find "Model" without an ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, parameters

Rails cannot find Model id in destroy method but works in new method. Not sure if I'm missing something glaringly obvious.

I am trying to destroy an instance of a subscription through the "Unsubscribe link". (Subscription is a joint table between User and Theme). The view is on the theme show page.

What I'm confused about is that I'm able to create an instance of a subscription with @theme = Theme.find(params[:theme_id]) in the new method but the error pulls up in the destroy method. See error below:

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in SubscriptionsController#destroy
Couldn't find Theme without an ID

Extracted source (around line #19):

```
def destroy
    @theme = Theme.find(params[:theme_id]) #line 19
    @current_sub = Subscription.where(:user_id => current_user.id, :theme_id => @theme.id)
    @current_sub.destroy
    flash[:notice] = "You have unsubscribed to #{@theme.name}"
```

subscriptions controller:

```
class SubscriptionsController < ApplicationController
def new
    @theme = Theme.find(params[:theme_id])
    @current_sub = Subscription.where(:user_id => current_user.id, :theme_id => @theme.id)
    while @current_sub.count == 0 do
        @subscription = Subscription.new
        @subscription.user_id = current_user.id
        @subscription.theme_id = @theme.id
            if @subscription.save
                flash[:notice] = "You have subscribed to #{@theme.name}"
                redirect_to root_path
            else
                render new
            end 
    end
end

def destroy
    @theme = Theme.find(params[:theme_id])
    @current_sub = Subscription.where(:user_id => current_user.id, :theme_id => @theme.id)
    @current_sub.destroy
    flash[:notice] = "You have unsubscribed to #{@theme.name}"
    redirect_to root_path
end
end
```

themes show view:

```
<h1>QUOTES, YO.</h1>
<br>
<h3>
<% if @current_sub.count == 0 %>
<%= link_to "Subscribe!", new_subscription_path(:user_id => current_user.id, :theme_id => @theme.id, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure you want to subscribe?' } )%>
<% else %>
<%= button_to "UnSubscribe!", subscription_path(@current_sub), :method => :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure you want to unsubscribe?' } %>
<% end %>
</h3>
<br>
<% @theme.inspirations.each do |i| %>
    <%= i.quote %>
    <br>
<% end %>
<br>
<%= link_to "Back to Main", root_path %>
```

themes controller:

```
class ThemesController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @themes = Theme.all
    end
    def show
        @theme = Theme.find(params[:id])
        @current_sub = Subscription.where(:user_id => current_user.id, :theme_id => @theme.id)
    end

private
def theme_params
        params.require(:theme).permit(:name)
     end
end
```

**Update**
This may not be the best option but I fixed my code by changing the controller to be:

```
def destroy
    @theme = Theme.find(params[:theme_id])
    @subscription = Subscription.where(:user_id => current_user.id, :theme_id => @theme.id)
    @subscription.destroy_all
    flash[:notice] = "You have unsubscribed to #{@theme.name}"
    redirect_to root_path
end
```

and view to pass in different params for the "Unsubscribe Link":

```
<h1>QUOTES, YO.</h1>
<br>
<h3>
<% if @current_subs.count == 0 %>
<%= link_to "Subscribe!", new_subscription_path(:user_id => current_user.id, :theme_id => @theme.id, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure you want to subscribe?' } )%>
<% else %>
<%= button_to "UnSubscribe!", subscription_path(:user_id => current_user.id, :theme_id => @theme.id), :method => :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure you want to unsubscribe?' } %>
<% end %>
</h3>
<br>
<% @theme.inspirations.each do |i| %>
    <%= i.quote %>
    <br>
<% end %>
<br>
<%= link_to "Back to Main", root_path %>
```

I'm not to too ecstatic about how i am calling @subscription.destroy_all since there really should only be one instance of a subscription between a user and a theme but it's working for now.

Answer (score 0):

See this line?

```
 <%= button_to "UnSubscribe!", subscription_path(@current_sub), :method => :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure you want to unsubscribe?' } %>
```

You don't have any mention of theme or theme_id, so you'll need to do this:

```
<%= button_to "UnSubscribe!", subscription_path(@current_sub, :theme_id => @theme.id) :method => :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure you want to unsubscribe?' } %>
```

This'll pass back the theme_id, so now you'll be able to use it properly in the controller.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But I still seem to be getting the same error. And is there a reason why i wouldn't need :theme_id => @theme.id) in the new method but would need it in the destroy method?

Comment: wouldn't need what? Could you print out the exact output your console is giving you?

Comment: Does `subscription_path(@current_sub), :theme_id => @theme.id` work?

Comment: basically it's not passing in that theme_id, that might be because it's not in the path, but that's a bit weird